# i created a instance without public ip, if i dont have public key how can i connect to that instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

If we create a instance without public IP, if we  don't have public key how can we connect to that instance.

I am best practice in creating and connect to the instance.

Comment: How did it go? Did the answer I posted helped you?

Answer (score 5):

> if we don't have public key how can we connect to that instance.

You can use [aws systems manager service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/session-manager.html)
Note:- ssm agent should be installed in the instance or the role should be attached to the instance with proper permissions.

here its the aws knowledge centre blog which clearly mentioned using aws systems manager is one of the best practices which ideally fits for your use case.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ssh-best-practices/